# Fill regions from contour based on cumsum

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pytorch, image-segmentation

I got an image for scene classification:

[image]

And using cumsum, I want to segment the three parts of it.

I take this simple operation in pytorch (can use tensorflow of course too, or python)

Comment: Can't you perform a cumulated sum bottom up, then `and` the two results ?

Comment: @BillKid it seems that there is no image now in your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`torch.flipud`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flipud.html#torch.flipud) to perform the `cumsum` in both directions:

```py
mask = (src_img.cumsum(dim=0) >0 ) + 2* torch.flipud(torch.flipud(src_img).cumsum(dim=0)>0)
```

Resulting with:

[image]